# gulp-preprocess not working as expected on a javascript file

Tags: gulp, gulp-preprocess

I'm running a very simple preprocess task in gulp and its not working as expected.

Here's the task:

```
import preprocess from 'gulp-preprocess'


function testpp() {
    return gulp.src('./test')
        .pipe(preprocess())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./tmp'))
}
```

The input file

```
 something

// @ifdef SOMEVAR

should be gone

// @endif
```

comes out unchanged.  I expected the part 'should be gone' to get removed.

The gulp-preprocess [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-preprocess) has this example:

```
// @ifdef DEBUG
someDebuggingCall();
// @endif
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
$ npm -v
6.10.1
$ gulp -v
CLI version: 2.2.0
Local version: 4.0.2
$ node -v
v10.16.0
```

From `package.json`

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.26.2",
    "eslint": "^6.1.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-babel": "^8.0.0-beta.2",
    "gulp-cli": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-preprocess": "^3.0.2",
    "through2": "^3.0.1",
    "transfob": "^1.0.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've solved this by now, but on the off chance you haven't, or someone else has the same problem, I'll tell you what I can see.

Using your example:

```
function testpp() {
    return gulp.src('./test')
        .pipe(preprocess())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./tmp'))
}
```

and

```
// @ifdef SOMEVAR

should be gone

// @endif
```

`SOMEVAR` will only be defined if it is defined in the context `preprocess` is working with.  By default, I think it inherits the `process` object context, which includes your local machine environment.  However, if you want to pass additional data to `preprocess`, you need to pass it a `context` object.  For example:

```
 return gulp.src('./test')
        .pipe(preprocess({
          SOMEVAR:42
        })
       .pipe(gulp.dest('./tmp'))
 ));
```

Then `SOMEVAR` is defined within the scope of the current task, and *should be gone* won't show.